# SAS loop by variable

Tags: sas

Trying to google it and couldnt find any (maybe it is me that is totally noob).

I want to make a new variable in my data set called step, that counts from 1 until customerid is changing.

Example:
This is the table I got:

```
Customerid  Page        step
1           Frontpage   
1           Middlepage  
2           Frontpage   
2           Middlepage  
2           Lastpage    
3           Frontpage   
3           Middlepage
```

What I want :

```
Customerid  Page       step
1           Frontpage   1
1           Middlepage  2
2           Frontpage   1
2           Middlepage  2
2           Lastpage    3
3           Frontpage   1
3           Middlepage  2
```

What I get right now:

```
Customerid  Page    step
1   Frontpage   1
1   Middlepage  2
2   Frontpage   3
2   Middlepage  4
2   Lastpage    5
3   Frontpage   6
3   Middlepage  7
```

I tried to do this in sas but it didnt work:

```
data nordea_dk1;
set nordea_dk;
by custerimd;
if first.customerid then do; 
step=1;
step + 1;
output;
run;
```

Comment: Make sure that the new variable `STEP` does not already exist on your input data set. That will prevent the values from being retained.

Comment: It does not, it was just for the sake of the example, but still does not work

Comment: Post sample data that shows the problem.

Comment: posted under: "what I get"

Comment: Your program generates this error message.  `ERROR 117-185: There was 1 unclosed DO block.` If I fix that then it generates this error instead. `ERROR: BY variable custerimd is not on input data set...` Perhaps you keep looking at an old version of the output data from version of the code that SAS could actually run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SAS log for notes or errors.  The basic logic works for your test data.

```
data have ;
 input Customerid Page $20. ;
cards;
1 Frontpage
1 Middlepage
2 Frontpage
2 Middlepage
2 Lastpage
3 Frontpage
3 Middlepage
;

data want ;
  set have ;
  by customerid ;
  if first.customerid then step=0;
  step+1;
run;
```

Comment: I also get that when I use your code.
Is it because in the real dataset the customerid is a text string?

Comment: No. FIRST. flags don't care if the variable is numeric or character.

Comment: with your help I find the issue! I have the customerid variable set to the name:
'Visitor ID <wt.vtid>'n

Then I changed it just to ID, it works like a charm for some reason :S.

Comment: That makes some sense. You results are consistent with the BY variable being a constant.

Answer (score 0):

A few syntactical items, there's a misspelling on `custerimd`, and the `do` is unnecessary. Also, the `output` isn't needed in this case since it's going to output at the end of the data step anyway as well.

In terms of the program logic, you need to reset the step on first.customerid, and increment it on additional values, thus an else case is needed. This should be what you're looking for:

```
data nordea_dk1;
    set nordea_dk;
    by customerid;

    if first.customerid then
        step=1;
    else
        step+1;

run;
```

Comment: Then I do that it just counts each observation. It does not group the count by the customerid variable?
I want it to reset to  1 when it comes to a new unique id in the variable customerid.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that the customerid is a text variable, do not know if that have any impact?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's a text variable, is the dataset sorted?